# "Unexpected attempt to get register for a value without a register" during release builds but not debug

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build, build-error

Debug builds work fine for me.  When I choose Active Build Variant = release, and try to run Build -> Generate Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK, the build runs for a while, then I get the following error:

> Unexpected attempt to get register for a value without a register in method `java.util.List com.chrynan.chords.parser.AsciiChordParser.parseLineAsString(java.lang.String, int, java.util.Set)`.

That is referencing an external library I'm pulling in.  Source code for that function is [available here](https://github.com/chRyNaN/chords/blob/master/core/src/commonMain/kotlin/com.chrynan.chords/parser/AsciiChordParser.kt).

What does that error mean?  My searches returned nothing remotely like it.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want to compile my app using the release build variant so that I can publish it to Google  Play.

Comment: No, what do you make with the code above, its look like an extension function right?

Comment: Oh actually I don't even use that function, but yes it's an extension function to convert text into Chords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!  I have no idea why, but I set `minifyEnabled = true` in my build.gradle (:app):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

This gave me instant crashing on app start due to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249005/minifyenabled-true-leads-to-crash-on-app-start/36261192), although I think that's unrelated.  I fixed that, and now my build works.

I still have no idea why that error came up though.

Answer (score 0):

For some one else having the same problem, I solved it by changing

> getDefaultProguardFile( 'proguard-android-optimize.txt') to
>   getDefaultProguardFile( 'proguard-android.txt') in build.gradle